is it good practice to compute booleans inside dto?
Here is my code, where the !!name && !!familyRole && !!gender part is computing isOnboarded value. Is it good practice to do such calculations inside DTO class ?
import { UserDocument } from 'src/users/schemas/user.schema';
import { FamilyRole, Gender } from '../users.types';

export class UserDto {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public email: string,
    public familyRole: FamilyRole,
    public gender: Gender,
    public createdAt: Date,
    public updatedAt: Date,
    public isOnboarded: boolean,
    public id: string,
  ) {}

  static from = ({
    name,
    email,
    familyRole,
    gender,
    createdAt,
    updatedAt,
    _id,
  }: UserDocument): UserDto => ({
    ...new UserDto(
      name,
      email,
      familyRole,
      gender,
      createdAt,
      updatedAt,
      !!name && !!familyRole && !!gender,
      _id.toHexString(),
    ),
  });
}

I tried to compute values inside DTO class model

Not a good idea because you moved the logic of how isOnboarded calculated inside DTO which should be simple object to carry data from one place to the other

Well as soon as you have logic in there, it's no longer a plain DTO… However one could argue that the object is still a plain data object without methods, as from is static. You might as well move that anywhere else though.

my solution was using virtual getter onboarded in my mongoose scheme
